# Why did the inquistor's head deflate after he died?

Tags: star-wars, tales-of-the-jedi

While watching the sixth episode of Tales of the Jedi, a sith inquisitor, voiced by [Clancy Brown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clancy_Brown):

> Fights with Ahsoka Tano, after finding her in a farming village, and is decapitated by her.

When the inquisitor dies, it appears that his head deflates:

> [image: Deflated Sith inquisitor head]

Is this down to the inquisitor's biology, or the fact that Ahoska was fighting some sort of dark-side apparation, or was he just a human-sized bag of hot air?

Comment: There can be only one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**(Currently) Unknown.**

So far the [Inquisitor](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Unidentified_Inquisitor_(Ahsoka_Tano)) in question hasn't been identified by his name or hierarchical number within the Inquisitorius, or by his species outside of the generic "humanoid" ascribed to him by Wookieepedia. As such, whether or not his apparent deflation was related to his biology, technology such as some kind of life support suit, or something else is up for grabs until more information comes out (if it ever does).